# i am not able to get all the results in api response? only 1 result is returned?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-restful, flask-appbuilder

i am new to flask and trying to build an api which return json response of all the posts in the database but  i am not able to get all of them only one post is returned.(i am using vanilla flask not  using any packages like 'flask-restful'). this is what i have tried.

```
from .db import get_db
from flask import jsonify,Blueprint
bp= Blueprint("api",__name__,url_prefix="/api")

@bp.route("/posts",methods=("GET",))
def get_posts():
    db = get_db()
    posts=db.execute('SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
   ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
   ' ORDER BY created DESC').fetchall()
   for post in posts:
     title=post["title"]
     body=post["body"]
     author=post["username"]
     return jsonify(
         title=title,
         body=body,
         author=author
     )'''
```

it only returns the first post in JSON format. i want all the posts.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are returning the result inside the for loop, consequently, it stops iterating and returns the first result.
You could create a list and append the jsonify to that list, or maybe your could use Marshmallow to do the serialization for you.
In case you want to create the list and append the result, here is what you can do:

```
post_list = []
for post in posts:
   ...
   post_list.append(jsonify(
     title=title,
     body=body,
     author=author
 ))
return post_list
```

Comment: i think the view function cannot return a list in response. it is not a valid response it can result in type error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jsonify returns a Flask `Response`, so trying to append it to list is not a good idea.
Like, how could you return few *Responses* from HTTP request?

The better idea is to store all your posts in list and **then** jsonify them.

```
post_list = []
for post in posts:
   title=post["title"]
   body=post["body"]
   author=post["username"]
   resp = {"title":title, "body":body, "author":author}
   post_list.append(resp)
return jsonify(post_list)
```